# SyntaxError: Unexpected token { when I return php arrays to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

I have a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` when I upload multiple files.
Whereas when I upload **just one file**, it works.

PHP

```
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

$arr = array();
foreach ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {

  if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
     $file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$key]);

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$key], $file)) {
         $arr['title'] = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$key];
         $arr['url'] = $file;
         $arr['size'] = $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'][$key];
     }
     echo json_encode($arr);
  }
}
```

JQUERY

```
 onComplete: function(file, response){
     response = JSON.parse(response);
     console.log('data = '+response.title);
     console.log('data = '+response.url);
     console.log('data = '+response.size);
 }
```

NEW VAR DUMP PHP (with @hek2mgl code)

```
array(2) {
[0]=>
    array(3) {
        ["title"]=> string(27) "facebook-icon-east-west.jpg"
        ["url"]=> string(35) "uploads/facebook-icon-east-west.jpg"
        ["size"]=> int(35227)
    }
[1]=>
    array(3) {
        ["title"]=> string(25) "facebook-graph-search.jpg"
        ["url"]=> string(33) "uploads/facebook-graph-search.jpg"
        ["size"]=> int(53122)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have specified `dataType: 'json'` in your request, you don't need to use `JSON.parse(response);` in the complete handler.

Comment: You may want to look at the returned JSON string, and check if you receive an object {} or an array []

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue How can I check that ?

Comment: In your way, you will receive a list of JSON object in a incorrect format. You need a JSON array instead, the answer of @hek2mlg may help.

Comment: window.alert(response) in the onComplete will present the JSON string.

Comment: @Steffi looks like you mixed var_dump with json output.

Comment: Check my update please, my var dump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You where output multiple json documents when multiple file had been uploaded. You'll have to wrap those multiple nodes into an array element.

You did:

```
{
   "title" : "dsfsd"
   ...
}
{<--- Syntax error
   "title" : "dsfsd"
   ...
}
```

You'll have to do:

```
[{
   "title" : "dsfsd"
   ...
},
{
   "title" : "dsfsd"
   ...
}]
```

Here comes the correct PHP code:

```
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';

$files = array();
foreach ($_FILES["uploadfile"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
  if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
     $path = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$key]);

     if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadfile']['tmp_name'][$key], $path)) {
         $files [] = array (
            'title' => $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'][$key],
            'url' => $path,
            'size' => $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'][$key]
         );
     }
  }
}

echo json_encode($files);
```

Comment: can you post the result of `var_dump($files)` ?

Comment: Check my var dump please, really weird. 2 files, 3 arrays ?

Comment: Now for one file, I have `undefined` and for two files : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`. It's not `{` anymore but `[`

Comment: Can you update the ouput of `var_dump($files);` should have been updated after the last update of my answer

Comment: Please get sure that you have the exactly PHP code as in my answer. The var_dump you posted can not be the output of my example. (Please reload this site)!

Comment: @hek2mgl Done... Always the same error. Check my update please

Comment: Oops, my bad. NO ERROR ANYMORE. My `json_encode($files)` was in the foreach. But now, I have "undefined" in Javascript

Comment: Hi @hek2mgl, it works !!! Thank you. Can you add this in your answer ? This is foreach, to get all the values in the array                 responses = JSON.parse(responses);

                `$.each(response, function() {
                    console.log('data = '+ this.title);
                    console.log('data = '+ this.url);
                    console.log('data = '+ this.size);
                });`

Comment: @Steffi Fine that it works now! :) Not sure why to add it. its not really related to my post. note that you can also drop answer for yourself, or at least add it end of the question

Comment: OMG, my code doesn't work anymore. No changes. I upload during 30 minutes files for testing. And now, the `json` returns me `[]`. What's going on !?